# Parsing string input from class into dirsync

Tags: python, methods

I'm making a program to sync files.
So far I've got it to save the directory inputs into a string but I can't call for it.

I get the error

```
    sync(self.folderone[0], self.foldertwo[0],'sync',verbose=True,content=True,purge=True,create=True)
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable'
```

Code:

```
# Invoke mover
from dirsync import sync
# Folder sync locations
class LOCATION():
    # Directory variables
    source_folder = []
    destination_folder = []
    parity_folders = []

    # Directory to be copied, add to list.
    def source_directory(self):
        sourcefolder = input("Select Source Directory: ")
        self.source_folder.append(sourcefolder)
    # Directory to be copied to, add to list.
    def destination_directory(self):
        destinationfolder = input("Select Destination Directory: ")
        self.destination_folder.append(destinationfolder)
    # Add both directories to a single string
    def concatenate_folders(self):
        self.parity_folders.append(LOCATION.source_folder)
        self.parity_folders.append(LOCATION.destination_folder)
    # Dump results to console
    def print_result_folders_source(self):
        print("You have selected the source directory: "+ self.source_folder[0])
    def print_result_folders_destination(self):
        print("You have selected the destination directory: "+ self.destination_folder[0])

# Location variables
folder_locations = LOCATION()
# Call class for user input on directories, then print to console.
folder_locations.source_directory()
folder_locations.print_result_folders_source()
folder_locations.destination_directory()
folder_locations.print_result_folders_destination()

class SYNC():
    # Sync variables
    folderone = folder_locations.source_directory
    foldertwo = folder_locations.destination_directory
    def user_sync(self):
#        print(folder_locations.source_directory[0,1]
        sync(self.folderone[0], self.foldertwo[0],'sync',verbose=True,content=True,purge=True,create=True)
#        sync(folder_locations.source_directory[0],folder_locations.destination_directory[0],'sync',verbose=True,content=True,purge=True,create=True)            

f_sync = SYNC()
f_sync.user_sync()
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means?

Comment: You should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you are trying to access 0th element of the list at self.folderone[0] but self.folderone is folder_locations.source_directory. I think you wanted to write

```
    folderone = folder_locations.source_folder
    foldertwo = folder_locations.destination_folder
```

as source_directory and destination_directory are methods of that class.